# Maven mysql integration tests example open source

Tags: mysql, maven-3

I am looking for some example where mysql intergration tests are done as part of maven build.

Can you please share some open source project code reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the open source project jcabi and their [pom.xml snippets: Usage of MySQL Maven Plugin for Integration Testing](http://mysql.jcabi.com/usage.html). You may found it not totally complete, but you may find the needed snippets e.g. [at github](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-mysql-maven-plugin/issues/26).